# Why my internal speakers and microphone are not working and I only have audio on my headphones and the HDMI outputs?

Tags: drivers, sound, microphone

I have been trying to repair my audio for 5 days now following a lot of repair suggestions but no success.
I decided to switch from Windows to Linux because of many reasons. On the Windows I had audio and microphone (on the speakers and microphone on the headphones) but I also remember that I had an issue a few months back when I had to update the audio drivers to be able to use zoom. I am open for suggestions.

My laptop model is:

- Aspire V15 Nitro – VN7-592G;

Sound card (chip Realtek ALC255):

- HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH / HDA Intel PCH at 0x94320000 irq 132;

Linux Distro:

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Release:        20.04
- Codename:       focal

Kernel:

- 5.10.4-051004-generic

Comment: Did you try to boot with a normal Ubuntu kernel instead of a mainline?

Comment: I did. 
After I installed the distro, I had no sound and thats' why I thought that maybe more recent kernel will do the work and fix it. 
But still a 'No' for me.